# Regex expression for digit strings without newlines

Tags: python, regex

Is there a way of using re.match(pattern, string) in the form bool(re.match(pattern,string)) such that the pattern returns True for strings which are wholly digit build (i.e. '1234' but not '12.4') but false for those which contain a newline AND whitespace (i.e. ' 1234' '1234 ' '\n1234' '1234\n')

So far I have bool(re.match("^[0-9]+$", pin)) which allows for wholly digits to be found

Comment: In what way is your existing code not working?

Comment: `^[0-9]+$` should work: [demo](https://regex101.com/r/GU2acY/1)

Comment: Non regex, you use [string.isdigit()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) which returns a bool if the string is solely digits or not.

Answer (score 0):

`re.fullmatch('\d+', string)` should do the trick.

If it returns `None` then it means that the string didn't match the pattern, if instead it returns a `Match` object then it fully matched.

For example:

```
import re

def wholly_digit(string):
    match = re.fullmatch('\d+', string)
    return match is not None
    
print(wholly_digit('1234'))
print(wholly_digit('1234 '))
print(wholly_digit('1234\n'))
print(wholly_digit('12.34'))
```

Output:

```
True
False
False
False
```